# wsdl objects are repeated when I add webservice reference

Tags: web-services, wsdl, xml-serialization

when I add webservice reference (not a service reference), I am getting same element with renamed added suffix as 1 as shown in the image. this causes an error when I try to debug. Inner exception says

Message=Types 'service.AddressType1' and 'service.AddressType' both use the XML type name, 'AddressType', from namespace 'xxx'. Use XML attributes to specify a unique XML name and/or namespace for the type.

I understand the error and I already saw some different threads here those tell me that I should specify different namespace but I don't have AddressType1 defined anywhere in my proxy classes. I have only AddressType. where from do I get that AddressType1 or others?
Anyone else got that error? thanks for your help.

[image: repeated objects]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was having inherited proxy classes which I generated using xsd2code tool. Problem was that this tool generated namespaces correctly for the parent xsd classes but when I check the class in the child which is shared/common by other parent classes, It appears that namespace field was empty as below. Therefore my service reference had same properties/classes more than one time with 1 suffix as shown in the question. I have just added same namespace for those child/inherited classes, It worked fine and no repeated properties. I hope that this helps to someone else having similar problem.

```
 System.Xml.Serialization.XmlRootAttribute([Namespace]:="", IsNullable:=True), _
```

Answer (score 1):

Have you looked at this answer? [Inheriting Existing .Net Class Serialization Error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8946405/inheriting-existing-net-class-serialization-error)

This answer also discusses issues with hierarchical namespacing (seems you may be doing that), so that may be your main issue: [Classes in different sub-namespaces all appear at top level in WSDL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1467968/classes-in-different-sub-namespaces-all-appear-at-top-level-in-wsdl)

It appears that you may need to specify the XmlTypeAttribute.  Can you provide your code sample for review?

Comment: I found the reason and solution through your 2nd link and replied below with more details. thank you.